# How to fix _ASSERT() inside CPPREST 2.10.2 in Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: c++, linux, boost, ubuntu-18.04, cpprest-sdk

I have preinstalled libcpprest-dev(version2.10.2) in ubuntu 18.04.
But when gives bad input getting _ASSERT(). This is a release build(with no symbol). But Still why getting _ASSERT(). How to get rid of this?

backtrace

```
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ffff57ee921 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff57de48a in __assert_fail_base (fmt=0x7ffff5965750 "%s%s%s:%u: %s%sAssertion `%s' failed.\n%n", 
    assertion=assertion@entry=0x7ffff7651bab "(bool)instream", 
    file=file@entry=0x7ffff7651c90 "/build/cpprest-2i1wUL/cpprest-2.10.2/Release/src/http/client/http_client.cpp", line=line@entry=103, 
    function=function@entry=0x7ffff76525c0 "virtual Concurrency::streams::streambuf<unsigned char> web::http::client::details::request_context::_get_readbuffer()") at assert.c:92
#3  0x00007ffff57de502 in __GI___assert_fail (assertion=0x7ffff7651bab "(bool)instream", 
    file=0x7ffff7651c90 "/build/cpprest-2i1wUL/cpprest-2.10.2/Release/src/http/client/http_client.cpp", line=103, 
    function=0x7ffff76525c0 "virtual Concurrency::streams::streambuf<unsigned char> web::http::client::details::request_context::**_get_readbuffer**()")
    at assert.c:101
#4  0x00007ffff7508ad7 in web::http::client::details::request_context::_get_readbuffer() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#5  0x00007ffff76237bc in web::http::client::details::asio_context::handle_write_large_body(boost::system::error_code const&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#6  0x00007ffff762396f in web::http::client::details::asio_context::handle_write_headers(boost::system::error_code const&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#7  0x00007ffff761de69 in boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >&>, boost::asio::const_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::asio::detail::write_streambuf_handler<std::allocator<char>, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, web::http::client::details::asio_context, boost::system::error_code const&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<std::shared_ptr<web::http::client::details::asio_context> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()> > > >::operator()(boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long, int) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#8  0x00007ffff761d7ad in boost::asio::ssl::detail::io_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::ssl::detail::write_op<boost::asio::const_buffers_1>, boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >&>, boost::asio::const_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::asio::detail::write_streambuf_handler<std::allocator<char>, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, web::http::client::details::asio_context, boost::system::error_code const&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<std::shared_ptr<web::http::client::details::asio_context> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()> > > > >::operator()(boost::system::error_code, unsigned long, int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#9  0x00007ffff761d5d5 in boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::asio::ssl::detail::io_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::ssl::detail::write_op<boost::asio::const_buffers_1>, boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >&>, boost::asio::const_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::asio::detail::write_streambuf_handler<std::allocator<char---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
p::client::details::asio_context, boost::system::error_code const&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<std::shared_ptr<web::http::client::details::asio_context> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()> > > > > >::operator()(boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long, int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#10 0x00007ffff76219be in boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_send_op<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::asio::ssl::detail::io_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::ssl::detail::write_op<boost::asio::const_buffers_1>, boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >&>, boost::asio::const_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::asio::detail::write_streambuf_handler<std::allocator<char>, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, web::http::client::details::asio_context, boost::system::error_code const&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<std::shared_ptr<web::http::client::details::asio_context> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()> > > > > > >::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service*, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#11 0x00007ffff7603740 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#12 0x00007ffff758b6f5 in boost_asio_detail_posix_thread_function () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#13 0x00007ffff61476db in start_thread (arg=0x7fff987f0700) at pthread_create.c:463
#14 0x00007ffff58cf71f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

Comment: ASSERT means serious logic errors - this should never happen. It it happens library author has a bug in a code or you are using API in wrong way. [Based on this assertion](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/master/Release/src/http/client/http_client.cpp#L172) I suspect that you are doing HTTP POST or PUT but you didn't provide a body content or something similar (body stream is in invalid state).

Comment: Let me put the use case - When I am providing all correct information then I get a good response. But if I give a wrong credential in the POST request then I see this ASSERT. But I did not change the structure of the POST message just changed one letter in the credential.

Comment: I am not Doubting my POST logic code as I tried the same in windows env. They're not seeing this ASSERT.

Comment: ASSERT usually depends on build flags and in release mode do not check anything. If library was build in different way on both platforms it is possible that assert is triggered only on one platform and have same issue.

Comment: Agree I just confirmed in Ubuntu cpprest is installed in a release. Where the ASSERT is happening. 
gdb <libcpprest.so>. shows no debug symbol. I installed it by apt-get cmd.